# Load several child collections with one query

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework-6

I'm using entity Framework 6.
On my database i have tables Students , Student_results , Student_Invoices and Student_Payments.

**Students** ( Id , Name , City , Age)

**Student_results** (Id , Date , Result , Student_ID)

**Student_Invoices** (Id , Date , Nr , Value , Student_ID)

**Student_Payments** ( Id ,Date , Type , Nr , Value , Student_ID )

I have a student in **MyStudent1** .
For this student I want to load all child entities with one query ( a single read from database)

How can i do this ?

Thank you !

Comment: You could start with sharing your entity classes, so we can see the setup :)

Comment: Look at the `Include` method on the `DbSet`.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I know the Include , but i don't know hot to load multiple child collection .

Comment: If calling `Include` once loads one set of related child entities, how do you suppose you load multiple sets of child entities?

Comment: @jmcilhinney The problem is that i have the student on MyStudent1. So my query should begin with : context.entry(MyStudent1)........ . I can't use .Include in this case.